# How to disable index.html on vue cli

Tags: vue.js, craftcms

I have installed vue cli on craft cms. The problem is that when I do npm run build as main index page the vue cli index.html page is displayed instead of the cms index page.
In the **vue.conf.js file** below I've tried to disable the index.html page but it doesn't work.

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {   

chainWebpack: config => {   

     
    config.plugins.delete('html');
    config.plugins.delete('preload');
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
}



};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to delete the generated index.html?
Edit your vue.config.js accordingly.

```
configureWebpack: { plugins: [ new ManifestPlugin({ fileName: modern ? "manifest.json" : "manifest-legacy.json", publicPath: production ? "/dist/" : "/" }), new FileManagerPlugin({ onEnd: { // Delete unnecessary index.html file delete: ["./web/dist/index.html"] } }) ] }
```